# Ubuntu Box with multiple NVIDIA graphic cards

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, nvidia-graphics-card, cuda

I recently bought a box from System76 that has multiple GPU's: one Quadro M6000, and two Tesla K40's.

When I do `lspci | grep -i nvidia` it says

```
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 17f0 (rev a1)
05:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fb0 (rev a1)
06:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK110BGL [Tesla K40c] (rev a1)
09:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK110BGL [Tesla K40c] (rev a1)
```

So, they're *there*.. But, when I do `nvidia-smi -L` it only shows

```
GPU 0: Quadro M6000 (UUID: GPU-09446504-6a9e-866a-a65d-0f1d55b7657b)
```

and, `ls -l /dev/nvidia*` shows

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 195,   0 Aug  9 03:29 /dev/nvidia0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 195, 255 Aug  9 03:29 /dev/nvidiactl
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 248,   0 Aug 12 16:19 /dev/nvidia-uvm
```

I can't be sure, but I'm guessing `/dev/nvidia0` is the Quadro M6000, and perhaps the fact that there isn't a `/dev/nvidia1` or a `/dev/nvidia2`, is another symptom (or perhaps the cause) of the box not seeing the Tesla K40's.. Also, my test programs that call [cudaGetDeviceCount](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__DEVICE_g665468e8cb33be42434f11bee2684ec9.html), yields only one GPU..

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.3, and I've installed `cuda_7.0.28_linux.run` (and installed the NVIDIA drivers via that run file.)

Why are the other cards inaccessible? How do I make them accessible?

Comment: I had so many issues trying to set up multiple Nvidia cards on Ubuntu I gave up. Better consult with Nvidia support directly: I'd you're into GPU computing they are actually good at helping you, but linux is not their forte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright! txbob over at [devtalk nvidia forums](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/865161/ubuntu-box-with-multiple-nvidia-gpu-cards/) gave me enough pointers to get to the solution.

So, basically, nouveau was interfering with the nvidia drivers, and even though I saw a `disable-nouveau` file in `/etc/modprobe.d`, it hadn't yet taken effect, because I didn't redo the `initramfs`...

So, to do that, I needed to do

```
rm -f /boot/initrd*
update-initramfs -c -k all
update-grub2
```

afterwards, running `nvidia-smi -L` yields

```
GPU 0: Quadro M6000 (UUID: GPU-09446504-6a9e-866a-a65d-0f1d55b7657b)
GPU 1: Tesla K40c (UUID: GPU-e992022a-724f-8f47-e08f-a954053020e6)
GPU 2: Tesla K40c (UUID: GPU-4d14695e-3e43-bf43-a3e3-91190f696d39)
```

So, all good now! Hopefully this might help someone else!

Answer (score 1):

Though the question is quite old, this may help someone.

I think the key step in your success was that you blacklisted the nouveau driver and reconfigured grub, so the `initramfs` stuff is unnecessary.

Source: [Bumblebee on a Lenovo T440p [NVidia GT 730M] with XUbuntu/Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://lenovolinux.blogspot.hu/2016/05/bumblebee-on-lenovo-t440p-nvidia-gt.html)